Rustで任意の構造体をトレイト境界Tとして扱いたい
Someであれば値を返し、NoneであればEmpty構造体を返すコードを書いたのですが
このEmpty構造体をTとして扱う(認識させる？)方法はあるのでしょうか
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct EmptyConfig {}

pub struct AppConfig<T> {
  pub file_path: PathBuf,
  config: T,
}

impl<T> AppConfig<T>
where
  T: for<'de> Deserialize<'de> + Serialize,
{
  pub fn new<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P, data: Option<T>) -> anyhow::Result<Self> {
    let path = path.as_ref();
    // ...
    let mut config: T = {
      // ここでconfigに
      // dataがSomeであれば中身を、NoneであればEmptyConfig構造体を代入したい
    }
    let mut conf = Self {
      file_path: path.to_path_buf(),
      config,
    };

    Ok(conf)
  }
}


おそらく現状のRustでは手段がありません
Tはあくまで仮の型なのでTとEmptyは異なる型です
コンパイル時にTが任意の型に変化するのであって、静的解析時点では境界に設定された型を実装すると仮定される仮想の型でしかありません
これを回避するにはトレイトのインスタンスを構造体でラップし、それを戻り値にインスタンスの指定を強制する設計が一つの案として挙げられます
以下はサンプルと結果です
fn main(){
        let d:&Check=&get(E::ZERO);
        println!("{}",d.result.get());
}

struct A{
    a:i32
}

struct B{
    a:i32
}

trait C{
    fn get(&self)->i32;
}

impl C for A{
    fn get(&self)->i32{
        self.a
    }
}

impl C for B{
    fn get(&self)->i32{
        self.a
    }
}

fn get(x:E)->Check<'static>{
    match x{
        E::ZERO=>Check{result:&A{a:10}},
        E::ONE=>Check{result:&B{a:5}}
    }
}

struct Check<'a>{
    result:&'a dyn C
}

enum E{
    ZERO,
    ONE
}

warning: variant `ONE` is never constructed
  --> compiler.rs:58:2
   |
56 | enum E{
   |      - variant in this enum
57 |     ZERO,
58 |     ONE
   |     ^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default

warning: 1 warning emitted

10


なるほど‥他のやり方を考えてみます、ありがとうございました！

match の結果の型は全て同じでなければなりません。 つまり value と Empty{} は同じ型です。 この場合は match の結果が関数の返却値でもあるので型 T は常に Empty でしかありえません。
T は Debug + Clone な性質を持つ型と制限を付けているので矛盾してしまっています。 これは制限であると同時に、これらの性質を満たしさえすればあらゆる型を受け入れるという意味でもあります。
記述に矛盾があるからエラーになっているので矛盾を解消しなければなりません。
関数の内容が正しいと仮定すれば T は Empty でしかありえないのですから最初から Empty を指定すればよいです。
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Empty {}

pub fn new(data: Option<Empty>) -> Empty {
  match data {
    Some(value) => value,
    None => Empty {},
  }
}

提示された関数から意図が読み取れないので関数の内容は正しい (関数の型の書き方が間違っている) と仮定しましたが、質問者の意図に沿った回答になっているでしょうか？
そうでない場合、質問者の意図がよりわかりやすくなるように質問文を修正してください。 その関数をどう使いたいのかという使用例を提示するとよいかもしれません。

すみません、質問が初めてだったので端折りすぎてしまいました
質問文を訂正させていただきました
